# Is there any way to disable a windows.form.timer inside a Task?

Tags: c#, timer, thread-safety, task

Is there any way to disable a windows.form.timer inside a task?

here is an example code that I have.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {runTask();} );
}
private void runTask()
{
     //Process here....
     timer1.enabled = false;
     MessageBox.Show(timer1.Enabled.ToString());
}
```

When I run the program the value of timer1.enabled is still true.
Is there anyway to disable the Timer inside a Task?

Comment: Yes, but I'd be *very* careful about timing issues here ... race-conditions and so forth. Methinks that I would send a custom message to the main thread, asking *him* to disable (what is basically "his" ...) timer.  Let the main thread be the [only ...] one to deal with the user-interface. . .  I think you'll be happier with it, that way.

Comment: I would `Invoke` the operation on the owner form, but there shouldn't be any other reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I seem not to get the concept. :D, can you give me a snippet of code please @RonBeyer

It would Greatly Help Me. Thanks

Comment: @MikeRobinson can you give me a snippet of code? :D.

It would greatly Help me. Thanks!

Comment: No, unfortunately, "not easily."  But I like Ron Beyer's `delegate` solution *much* better.  The essence of my comment was simply that ... "let the *main* thread, and only that thread, be the only one to (have to) deal with the Windows GUI.  The correct operation of any GUI is *very* dependent upon the flow of "Windows messages," and IMHO you just *don't* want other threads to be involved with that sort of thing.  "*Don't* 'race the user-interface!"  You will be most-unhappy if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the timer works just fine, you can easily tell by not getting a screenful of message boxes.  It is your test code that is the problem, it has a threading race bug.  Also easy to see by sleeping for a bit:

```
    private void runTask() {
        //Process here....
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        MessageBox.Show(timer1.Enabled.ToString());
    }
```

You now see "False".  You see the exact same bug by changing @Ron's snippet and use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

The Timer class is already thread-safe for stopping and doesn't need any help.  You can see it from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Timer.cs,3e8f21e63fbaabe2), note the call to PostMessage().  It is however not safe for starting the timer, worker threads don't run a dispatcher loop so the Tick event won't fire.

You don't have a problem, don't fix it.

Comment: Yes, the Invoke just circumvents the problem by (I think) blocking the call and completing on the main thread before returning to the worker thread.

Comment: is system.threading.thread.sleep() safe to use inside a Task?

Comment: It is not unsafe.  You only lose elegant points, use Task.Delay() instead.